# Output the names of bosses who manage multiple employees

Tags: sql

I have a database of personnel which has an EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME and BOSS_ID. I'm trying to display the employee_name of all bosses who manage 3 or more people. The following query provides me with all the right BOSS_ID's.

```
SELECT BOSS_ID FROM PERSONNEL
GROUP BY BOSS_ID
HAVING COUNT(BOSS_ID) >= 3
```

However I wish to only display the EMPLOYEE_NAME of the bosses, not their BOSS_ID. I tried this, but it produced no names at all.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM PERSONNEL
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(BOSS_ID) >= 3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Manager Name your can do `Self Join`.

In the below example to get the Manager name you need to get it from `P2` Reference.

```
SELECT DISTINCT P2.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS ManagerName
FROM PERSONNEL P1
JOIN PERSONNEL P2 ON P1.BOSS_ID = P2.EMPLOYEE_ID
GROUP BY P2.EMPLOYEE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(P1.BOSS_ID) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a JOIN on the same table to obtain the boss's name.

```
SELECT p.Employee_name, b.Employee_name as "Boss Name"
FROM personnel p
INNER JOIN personnel b ON b.Employee_ID = p.Boss_ID
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try using a subquery.

```
SELECT Employee_name
FROM PERSONNEL
where BOSS_ID IN (

SELECT BOSS_ID FROM PERSONNEL
GROUP BY BOSS_ID
HAVING COUNT(BOSS_ID) >= 3
)
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AtBdYgSf)